# Where and how does fontspec.sty specify the default font (Latin Modern Roman)?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, default

When doing `\usepackage{fontspec}`, where and how is the default font name specified?

On my TeX Live 2019, I see this font filename on the console log of the *lualatex* compilation:  `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf`. Where is it configured?

FYI I wasn't able to find anything useful by eyeballing the output of `grep -iE 'lmodern|latin.?modern' $(dpkg -L texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-luatex) 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: The default font  is indeed Latin Modern.

Comment: @Bernard: I know that the default font is Latin Modern. I'm interested in which config file specifies it. Do you know?

Comment: I thought you wondered which was the default font. As far as I understand LaTeX 3 code, it seems to be set in lines 475–477 of `fontspec-luatex.sty` and `fontspec-xetex.sty`.

Comment: note that TU encoded  latin modern is already the default in lualatex (since 2015) even before fontspec is loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Latin Modern fonts are preloaded at format creation. If you look in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.log
```

(the location may vary depending on the flavor of TeX Live you're using) you find

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tulmr.fd
File: tulmr.fd 2017/01/26 v1.8 Standard LaTeX font definitions for Latin Modern
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tulmss.fd
File: tulmss.fd 2017/01/26 v1.8 Standard LaTeX font definitions for Latin Modern
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tulmtt.fd
File: tulmtt.fd 2017/01/26 v1.8 Standard LaTeX font definitions for Latin Modern
)
```

Similarly for `lualatex.log`.

This is because if the engine is XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, the default encoding is set to TU and the default font family to `lmr`. The file `tulmr.fd` contains

```
\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{lmr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{lmr}{m}{n}%
  {<-5.5>    \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman5-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <5.5-6.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman6-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <6.5-7.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman7-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <7.5-8.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman8-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <8.5-9.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman9-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <9.5-11>  \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman10-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <11-15>   \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman12-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <15-> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman17-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   }{}
```

and other font definitions.

It's no longer a job for `fontspec` to define the standard fonts, as it used to be up to TeX Live 2015.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! FYI my *fontmath.cfg* contains `cmr` fonts, but *lmodern.sty* specifies `lmr` for math as well. So running `\usepackage{lmodern}` makes a difference: `lmmi10.pfb` will be used instead of `cmmi10.pfb` for math.