# fontspec: \addfontfeatures does not work

Tags: fonts, fontspec

In the example below, I add some features to the default LaTeX font by `\addfontfeatures` and compiled by `XeLatex`, but all of these features does not work. Why and how to make them work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeatures{Color=123456,Opacity=0.3,Scale=5}
ABCD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a font first? `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}` or whatever font you want to use.

Comment: `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` if you want the default font.

Comment: Though I don't give the font name expictly, I think `LaTex` will allocate a default font. Why does `\addfontfeatures` not apply its features to this default font?

Comment: And, if the font name must be given expictly, how can I get the name of the default font in `LaTex`?

Comment: look into the log. There is a large warning: `Package fontspec Warning: \addfontfeature(s) ignored on line 41; it cannot be
used with a font that wasn't selected by a fontspec command.` The default fonts are loaded with fd-files.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer. What are `fd-files`? Where are they?

Comment: tulmr.fd is in tex/latex/base.

Comment: When I use `\fontname\font` to print the default font, I get `[lmroman10-regular]`. It seems not to be `Latin Modern Roman` font. Then I `\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular}`, this causes error. So, what is on earth the name of the default font in LaTeX/XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment: adding `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` at the begin of the document works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\addfontfeatures{Color=123456,Opacity=0.3,Scale=5}
ABCD
\end{document}
```

---

Some extra information.

1. The default font **is** Latin Modern Roman.

   [Where and how does fontspec.sty specify the default font (Latin Modern Roman)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470008/250119)

   [Why is Latin Modern the default font with xelatex and lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513534/250119)
2. This answer explains what `.fd` file do. [How do fonts work in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338049/250119)
3. `\fontname\font` does not necessarily give the family name. Quote from fontspec documentation:

   [image: fontspec documentation]

   Experimentally, it looks like `\fontname` will give whatever you pass as input to `\font` command.

   ```tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \begin{document}

   \font\abc=[[[lmroman9-regular\relax
   \abc
   \fontname\font

   \font\deg={Latin Modern Roman}\relax
   \deg
   \fontname\font

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: output image]
4. I don't know why fontspec and LaTeX core does not work together out of the box.