# LetterSpace in font spec does not work

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I would like to squeeze the characters within specific words a little bit.
(I know it's bad typography , but in this case it is necessary.)

I have tried using the LetterSpace feature with `\addfontfeature`, but nothing changes.

Here is my MWE:

```
% xelatex !
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}           % for xelatex 
\begin{document}
\noindent
2022--2025  \\
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0} 2022--2025} \\
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-10.0} 2022--2025}
\end{document}
```

I have also googled a bit, but could not find a solution / reason why it does not work.

All hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to invoke `fontspec` with `\setmainfont{...}`

Comment: You get the warning `\addfontfeature(s) ignored on line 6; it cannot be used with a font that wasn't selected by a fontspec command.`

Comment: Duplicate of [fonts - fontspec: \addfontfeatures does not work - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643918/fontspec-addfontfeatures-does-not-work)